# value in array isn't indexed

Tags: php, mysql

This script should select StaffID from the database and then put it into an array and then from there I can put it into a variable to be used in the next query.

```
$query  = "SELECT StaffID FROM staff WHERE First_Name = '$db_staff_member_first_name' AND Last_Name = '$db_staff_member_last_name'";
    $result = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
    echo $result;
    echo $query + "<br>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
$db_staffid = $row['staffID'];
}
```

after the script is ran I get

```
'Resource id #4SELECT CustomerID FROM customer WHERE Customer_First_Name = 'Christopher' AND Customer_Last_Name = 'Bennett'Resource id #50'
```

and then the following notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: staffID in
>   E:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\Placing_Orders.php on line 112

Why is this?

Comment: what do you get if you print_r($row)

Comment: The field name in the query is with upper case `S`, the other is with lower case `s`. See @God's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16521487/1333512

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

`Note: Field names returned by this function are case-sensitive.`